# Paste text from clipboard directly to browser and make Google search for it

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

When we need to paste something to Google Search from our clipboard, we need at least two or more clicks, before we can get to *URL* bar and hit `CTRL+V` and then `Enter` to start searching.

I was thinking to make it in one click?

Comment: If you're already in a Chrome window, you can type `Ctrl+L` `Ctrl+V` `Enter`.

Comment: @Gilles Well, we all know this, yes it's ture but it's not that handy. Besides you could also do `ALT+D` `CTRL+V` `Enter`. But this is too long. Now all I do is to double-click on the text with mouse (make it selected) and then click one single button to deliver it Google Search or Google Translate (with another button). You don't even have to copy text to clipboard really - just select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution happen to be very easy and straight forward. It will help you to open a browser, paste text from your clipboard to Google Search - all with one little script, that can be and must be attached to a keyboard shortcut.

What we need, is a small utility called `xsel` and few lines in *BASH* script.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
CLIPBOARD=$(/usr/bin/xsel --clipboard)
/usr/bin/xdotool search --name "Google Chrome" windowactivate
/usr/bin/google-chrome https://www.google.com/search?q="${CLIPBOARD/\&/%26}" --window --maximize
```

**Explanations:**

1. Save your present clipboard data to `CLIPBOARD` variable, by running `xsel --clipboard`
2. Make sure to really show the browser window (in my case Google Chrome) and not to run in background, by using `xdotool`
3. Pass saved and escaped variable as an argument to a browser and make sure that it pops up maximized in-front of other open programs by passing `--window --maximize` to a command line.
4. Next you would need to save the content of the exampled script to a *file* and make it *executable*. At last, set a shortcut on newly created script. I user Gnome and adding a shortcut to a script as easy as it gets.

Now, when I click on, previously pretty useless `Eject` key, I get data from my clipboard being sent directly to *Google Search* with only a ***single click***.

#### EDIT 1:

In case you wish to avoid copying text to clipboard and make it event *shorter* and *faster*, you can work just *on selection* (*on selected text*). All you need is to replace `/usr/bin/xsel --clipboard` with `/usr/bin/xsel --primary`. Now, the *selected text* will be passed to Google Search upon invoking the script, even without copying it to clipboard, which makes the whole process much more efficient.

#### EDIT 2:

In addition, as correctly mentioned by *[Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)*, it's nessesary to escape `&` and replace it with `%26`, otherwise Google will interpret it literally and search query would break on it.

> Update: For replacing `&` with `%26` find and change in previous code:
>
> `"${CLIPBOARD}"` -> `"${CLIPBOARD/\&/%26}"`

Comment: Why do you call `xdotool`? Chrome raises the existing target window when you run `google-chrome` and an instance is already started. You should encode to escape characters that can't be used in URLs.

Comment: @Gilles My friend, what you're saying is only true if Chrome is not running by the time you call it. If it's opened and you have other windows running or you are in the other program - then Chrome would start in background and you get notification. At least it happens on GNU/Linux with Fedora/GNOME. About URL encoding/escaping - well, it's what Google does on server side. There is absolutely no reason to encode/escape anything as it's done automatically. Check it out: https://www.google.com/search?q=welcome home it's home there's no other place like <strong>home</strong>. - see what you get.

Comment: Ok, Chrome does raise the existing window for me with Sawfish. You do need to escape special characters, it can't be done automatically since the characters would be interpreted as special characters. The special characters in URLs aren't the same as in HTML: `<>` are ok, but you absolutely need to escape at least `&`.

Comment: @Gilles Exactly, I missed that. `&` always interpreted literally in URL. Fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh

mk_google_query() {
    url_encode() {
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/298258/3541063
        perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);' "$1"
    }
    echo "http://google.com/search?q=`url_encode "$1"`"
}

SEARCH_TEXT=`xsel`
xdg-open `mk_google_query "$SEARCH_TEXT"`
```

This script uses `xsel` to read the clipboard, `xdg-open` to open the default browser and `perl` with `URI::Escape` module to url-encode the search query.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Encoding is not always good and I'm using same scenario not only for Google Search, besides there is only one character that you really need to escape, which is `&`.

Moreover try checking your code with `love & hate` query.

Comment: @Ilia, I've checked the script with "love & hate" text in the clipboard and it works perfectly (Linux Mint 17 & Firefox). Also URL encoding will at least always work (if not strictly necessary).
Considering other search engines, it simple to modify the query - tell me if you're experiencing troubles with some search site.